# "I have a road trip planned on Friday"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I need to send my car for maintenance and I wanted to ask if they can return my car by certain date. I am supposed to drive my car for road trip on the Friday of that week. So I asked:

> I have a road trip planned on Friday. So can we ensure I get my car back by then?

Not sure if the above sentence sounds natural and correct. What are some other natural ways to express this?

Comment: See my other answer.  Instead of planing a "launch and leave" question, expect to have a dialogue. However this seems clear and natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to say

> Will you commit to getting the car back to me before Friday?

or

> Will you promise that I will have my car back before Friday?

I am being fussy, but you are not ensuring anything so "we" is somewhat off the mark. "Ensure" is not the best word to use when when you are asking for a commitment or a promise. (It is not wrong, but why not be as explicit as possible.) Finally, you are not interested in whether they are merely able to get the car back to you before Friday. You want to know they definitely will do so.

As I said, I am being fussy. What you said will be understood.

Comment: Thanks! if I'd like to add the reason why I need the car by Friday, which is the road trip, how would you go about adding that?

Comment: Sorry. I actually have been on a road trip. The way you started is fine. "Ihave a road trip planned on Friday. Will you promise that my car will be ready before Friday?"

Comment: how was your road trip? Btw I wonder can I use `guarantee` in this case as in "can you guarantee that I will get my car back by Friday"?

Comment: It was pleasant, thank you, right time of year to be in the American South. You can use "guarantee" in this sense in most contexts, but it has legal connotations so I personally would not use it except in a context where those connotations apply.